# Why is "Ready for the Mosh Pit, Shaka Brah" considered cringeworthy?

Tags: life-is-strange

I've read many times that Life is Strange dialogs are sometimes awkward. Since english is not my native language, I can't really be judge if a given sentence is "proper" US slang or not, but I can at least understand why a specific word (such as "hellas") or way of saying things could be felt out of place. In the case of the (in)famous ["Ready for the mosh pit, shaka brah"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RW3LO-MlTMI&feature=youtu.be&t=1h15m20s) however, I'm clueless. Why is this sentence considered so cringeworthy, both out of game and in game, since Chloe itself finds it lame? Is it the mosh part or the shaka part? Or both? Or maybe it is the way Max says it? I'm clueless, like I've said.

Comment: This is too subjective to be answerable in anything approaching objectivity.

Answer (score 7):

I think its mostly because of how *lame* the statement is that makes in cringe worthy.  Just a few seconds before when Max says this line, Chloe says that they will "make a thrasher out of you yet."  What Chloe means in basically make Max into someone that's more like Chloe's style (her rebel-punk style).

Shaka refers to the [Shaka sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaka_sign) you can make with your hand:

[image: Shaka sign]

This hand sign is sometimes referred to as "hang loose," and according to Wikipedia, is common among surf culture in California, and in Hawaii.  If you don't know already, a [mosh pit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshing) is something you normally see at rock or metal concerts.  Usually, they are very rough, and if you aren't paying attention, you could even get hurt in one!

In summary, Max is basically saying something that is pretty lame for someone her style to say.  She thought she was being cool, but she really wasn't.  It's just something you wouldn't expect for her to say, or really anyone, including people like Chloe.  It's kind of like asking someone for a high five or fist bump when its not really appropriate.